# Is there a way I can print a statement with an exclamation mark and a quotation mark?

Tags: python-3.9

I'm trying to print a statement that looks like this: `"Oh no!"`,
but I keep getting: `Oh no!` without the quotes.

This is the code I've been using:

```
print(exclamation.capitalize() + ("!") , "I yelled" + ".")
```

Please what am I missing?

Comment: ```print('"Oh no!"')``` or ```print("\"Oh no!\"")``` ?

Comment: Check out the python tutorial on string literals https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/introduction.html#strings , it will probably help you.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.6+, you can use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) to embed statements directly in the string.

Also, if you use single quotes to capture the string, you can use double-quotes in the string and they will print without needing to be escaped.

```py
print(f'"{exclamation.capitalize()}"! I yelled.')
```